# Bash option to get resolved executable path?

Tags: bash, debugging

Bash is able to trace execution script commands with the `-x` command line option. Each command is then output to `stderr`, prefixed by `PS4` as stated in the man page.

> ```
>  -x      After expanding each simple command, for command,  case  command,
>          select  command,  or arithmetic for command, display the expanded
>          value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded  arguments
>          or associated word list.
> ```

Albeit useful, the resolved executable path of each command is not given. So I have to figure out which executable has been run by guessing shell aliases and `PATH` value while reading execution trace.

For example, `ruby` has multiple command candidates on my workstation:

```
$ type -a ruby
ruby is /home/cbliard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
ruby is /home/cbliard/.rvm/bin/ruby
ruby is /usr/bin/ruby
ruby is /home/cbliard/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

If executing this script with `/bin/bash -x`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "compute"
ruby script/run_something.rb
echo "deploy"
bundle install
bundle exec cap deploy
```

Trace execution will be

```
+ echo "compute"
compute
+ ruby script/run_something.rb
[output of ruby script]
+ bundle install
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
[...]
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
+ bundle exec cap deploy
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2014-01-14 09:12:42 executing `deploy'
  * 2014-01-14 09:12:42 executing `deploy:update'
[...]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I had some oddities with resolved executables, mainly due to my usage of [`rvm`](http://rvm.io/). The output I would like is with fully resolved path, like this:

```
+ [builtin] echo "compute"
compute
+ /home/cbliard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby script/run_something.rb
[output of ruby script]
+ /home/cbliard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/bundle install
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
[...]
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
+ /home/cbliard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/bundle exec cap deploy
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2014-01-14 09:12:42 executing `deploy'
  * 2014-01-14 09:12:42 executing `deploy:update'
[...]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Having the resolved command would really help me debugging weird `rvm`/`bundler` issues. The `-x` option helps a lot but sometimes it is not enough. **Is there any trick that helps knowing the full characteristics of the commands while running a `bash` script?**. It is better if the original script does not have to be modified.

Comment: You could give your script such a command line option.

Comment: Yes, but doing it without modifying the script would be better. I saw on http://binfalse.de/2012/09/howto-debug-bash-scripts/ that PS4 can be customized. Maybe it is possible to customize this prompt more and make it display the full executable path.

Comment: @rhamu and other closers, before voting to close, please add a comment to say what you find unclear in the question. I personally find it as clear as can be, so wouldn't know how to improve it (and I was not the one asking the question).

Comment: I am currently editing my question to make it clearer

Comment: @rhamu & others Is it better like this? How can I improve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an approximation, you could do:

```
trap '{ type -p -- "${BASH_COMMAND%% *}" >&3; } 3>&2 2> /dev/null' DEBUG
set -o functrace -o xtrace
```

The `DEBUG` trap is run before every command. During the execution of that trap, `$BASH_COMMAND` is set to the current command. That includes function calls, builtins, assignments... We call `type -p` on the first part of that up to the first space character with `type`'s stdout retdirected to the shell's stderr (via fd 3, so that the `xtrace` output is redirected to `/dev/null`).

That's an approximation in that it won't work in cases like `"cmd" foo` or `$CMD foo`. Like for `xtrace`, beware of redirections of stderr.

Without modifying the script:

```
BASH_ENV=<(cat <<'EOF'
  trap '{ type -p -- "${BASH_COMMAND%% *}" >&3; } 3>&2 2> /dev/null' DEBUG
EOF) bash -o functrace -x your-script
```

Or to have it in the `PS4` prompt:

```
BASH_ENV=<(cat <<'EOF'
  { trap '{ cmdpath=$(type -p -- "${BASH_COMMAND%% *}")
      } 2> /dev/null' DEBUG;} 2> /dev/null
EOF) PS4='+[$cmdpath] ' bash -o functrace -x your-script
```

or to avoid the fork:

```
BASH_ENV=<(cat <<'EOF'
  { trap '{ hash -- "${BASH_COMMAND%% *}";} 2> /dev/null' DEBUG;}2>/dev/null
EOF) PS4='+[${BASH_CMDS[${BASH_COMMAND%% *}]}] ' bash -o functrace -x your-script
```

Comment: Useful hack. Thanks! I used `type` without the `-p` option.